# How to convert this javascript code to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert [this javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378680/get-all-the-values-of-a-dropdownlist-to-an-array-using-javascript) to jquery ?

```
var ddlArray= new Array();
var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl');
for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
   ddlArray[i] = ddl .options[i].value;
}
```

I think one can convert `ddl = document.getElementById('ddl');` to `ddl = $('#ddl');` but what can be done to the loop ?

Comment: But why? The original code works in every browser since IE5, is future proof, not reliant on any library, is easily maintained by anyone with basic javascript knowledge and runs [very much faster](http://jsperf.com/options-iteration-20141012a). The only part where jQuery would be useful is in getting the value of the options, but the accepted answer doesn't use it for that.

Comment: I didn't know jquery was so much slower, does it mean that one shouldn't use jquery ?

Comment: Not my decision, but you should be aware of all factors when making decisions. If you just want less code (which isn't a good reason on its own), a plain JS version is `var ddlArray = [].map.call(document.getElementById('ddl').options, function(opt){return opt.value;});`. Note that you'll need a [polyfill for *.map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for IE8, there are libraries to give IE 8 ES5 features.

Comment: taste the future (or now in ff, ch): [].map.call(dd1.options, (a) => a.value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) + [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
var ddlArray = $('#ddl option').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).toArray();
```

Or [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) + the generic iterator [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var ddlArray = $.map($('#ddl option').toArray(), function(option) {
    return option.value;
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5bgcwtkj/7/)

Comment: Thank you, do you know where I could find the documentation to learn to do this kind of things ?

Comment: @Wicelo no problem, I've just added links to the jQuery API docs in the answer. `=]`

Comment: You don't even need to call `$.makeArray`, just `$.map` over the array-like jQuery collection.

Comment: @Bergi I'm aware of that, however the [documentation for `$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) frowns upon iterating array-like objects without first converting them to real arrays: "Array-like objects — those with a `.length` property and a value on the `.length - 1` index — must be converted to actual arrays before being passed to `$.map()`. The jQuery library provides [`$.makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) for such conversions."

Comment: @Bergi in my actual code, I have never used `$.makeArray()` for this use case either, but it is good to keep answers inline with the docs for future-proofness I believe. Anyway, I've switched `$.makeArray()` by `.toArray()` to make that sample less ugly.

Comment: you could use [].map.call instead of $.map if you want to feed it an almost-array.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis, only issue with `Array#map` is that it is not natively supported in ES3 environments (IE<=8). I don't know if anyone still cares about those ancient browsers without using an ES5-shim, but that's the main reason I'm using the jQuery version of `map`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté—IE 8 still has around [20% user share](http://netmarketshare.com). You may not care about that but your clients might. Adding polyfills for ES3 browsers doesn't hurt.

Comment: @RobG according to StatCounter, [IE8 has less than 5% market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201309-201409), which I believe to be more accurate seeing as the sites which I have access to the analytics had less than 1% IE8 usage even when we still supported IE8. Well, this varies a lot depending on your target audience. I'm happy that I could drop ancient browsers support easily, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté—sites that do not work with IE8 are unlikely to get many IE 8 visitors. ;-) Browser stats are extremely unreliable, but they probably show trends OK. Bringing ES3 browsers up to ES5 isn't hard, there are [libraries to help with that](https://github.com/es-shims). ;-)

Comment: @RobG if you re-read my comment above, I've mentioned "less than 1% IE8 usage **even when we still supported IE8**", in fact, the site I'm mentioning had full IE6-8 support until a year or so ago. I've also addressed ES5-shim in my [original comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331032/how-to-convert-this-javascript-code-to-jquery/26331060?noredirect=1#comment41326827_26331060) and I agree with you. `=]`